# How can I offer secure links when selling downloads with Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm interested in selling e-books on my site that will come packaged as a ZIP file. I've got the purchase process all hooked up using Stripe's Checkout feature. Once I make a test purchase it's sending me to my "Thank You" page and creating the new customer (cia Stripe_Customer::create) and charge (via Stripe_Charge::create).

How can I offer a download link on this page that can't then just be passed around to anyone else? Is it safer to just ask for their email address and email the ZIP to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do would probably be to create a download token object in your database, and to have that know about the user and the creation time. Then, the user's download link can be something like `download.php?token=f136803ab9c241079ba0cc1b5d02ee77`.

When download.php sees a token, it can 1) make sure that it's valid, and 2) that it's being used within n minutes of when the token was created. (And maybe that it's been used fewer than 10 times, or something like that.)

Obviously, this means that the user can't redownload his/her ebook -- you'll need some way of regenerating/reissuing tokens if you want to support that use case.